# How to call another test during my test in Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I have a problem when creating test with Cypress
I am creating a test to which is required that the user should be in logged on his account to be able to run the test.
I have another test to test the log in function.
How can I run the test (Create account) so i dont need to have the code in the beginning of every test to log in first as in the example.

I start always with the log in script before I run the test.As u see I have the username and the password for each test.
I want to be able to run the log in first and then the rest.

```
cy.visit('https://devcloudarena.devtest.fastighet.vitec.se/test/mina-sidor/logga-in')
cy.contains('Mina sidor').click()
cy.contains('Logga in').click()
cy.get('#UserId').click();
cy.get('#UserId').type('19380412-6526');
cy.get('#Password').click();
cy.get('#Password').type('Vitec.Test20');
cy.get('.ml-auto > .button').click();
cy.wait('@getActivities').then((xhr) => { });

cy.url().should('contains', 'https://devcloudarena.devtest.fastighet.vitec.se/test/mina-sidor');
cy.get('.d-block .col-9').click();
cy.url().should('contains', 'https://devcloudarena.devtest.fastighet.vitec.se/test/mina-sidor/min-profil');
cy.get('.object-description-cc > a').click();
cy.url().should('contains', 'https://devcloudarena.devtest.fastighet.vitec.se/test/mina-sidor/uppdatera-kontaktuppgifter');
cy.get('.form-group > .button').click();
cy.get('#RegisterForm').submit();
cy.url().should('contains', 'https://devcloudarena.devtest.fastighet.vitec.se/test/mina-sidor');
```

Comment: which portion of the code you want to reuse, can you update that in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it as a [Custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html) and it will be reusable in every test with a simple command call.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Rosen Mihaylov's answer, the user could convert the login script into a `custom command` and also use `hooks` to implement the pre-condition of the test by calling that specific custom command.

custom command pertaining to support/command.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, pw) => {})
```

using the custom command in the spec file

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login()
})
```